# Unwanted text indent in html/css tabs

Tags: html, css

I have the tabs written in `HTML` and `CSS`.

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvvn8xdx/). The problem is that the text in the first and the second panels have the text indent. But on the third panel everything is ok. How to remove this unwanted indent. Thanks.

Comment: looks all three are same in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label { border-bottom: 1px !important; }
```

or remove this css

```
.korpus input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
 }
```

Edited

```
.korpus input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this removed the text indent, but my tabs don't work anymore.

Comment: no like this am saying .korpus input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

Comment: Changing border-bottom from 2px to 1px solved my problem)) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

punitha's solution works, but assuming what you want it is to make each tab correspond to the bottom text, set the border-bottom to none.

```
.korpus input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border-bottom: none;
 }
```

Comment: The first two panels is working, but the indent appeared on the third panel

Comment: Ah, the "1px solid white" might be the best bet then.